# Showing sub-categories on Menu

Tags: php, mysql, categories

My category table is like:

```
id - title - sub
```

*If sub is 0 it means it's main category.

With code below I can list my main catagories like;

- Main 1
- Main 2
- Main 3

Here is code;

```
  <?php

function menucategories() {
include ('connect.php');

$q=mysql_query("select  * from categories where sub='0' order by asc");
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))

    echo "<a class='cat' href='cat.php?id=$r[id]'>- $r[title]</a>";
}

?>
```

But I want to list like that;

- Main 1

-sub 1.1

-sub 1.2

- Main 2

-sub 2.1

-sub 2.2

I am very beginner and I couldn't find a way. So, I am waiting for your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386915/3150981. Here you can align Category -> Sub Category ->Sub Category ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
function menucategories() {
include ('connect.php');

$q=mysql_query("select  * from categories where sub='0' order by asc");
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

    echo "<a class='cat' href='cat.php?id=$r[id]'>- $r[title]</a>";
    $q1=mysql_query("select  * from categories where sub='".$r[id]."' order by asc");
    while ($r1=mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
        echo "<a class='cat' href='cat.php?id=$r1[id]'>-- $r1[title]</a>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code did the trick. After a little touch. sub='".$r[id]."' part suppossed to be sub='".$r['id']."' like that, and it's working. thanks a lot.