# BelongsToMany Through

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have this table

```
    class Account extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'account_id', 'id');
    }
```

```
class Post extends Model

{
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_id', 'id');
    }

    public function positions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post_categories');
    }
```

```
class Position extends Model
{
    use NodeTrait;

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post ::class, 'post_categories');
    }
```

As it is known, an account can have a number of posts and each post has a number of categories.And each category can also have subsets (with children).I want to know directly what categories each account has used with the children of that category.

I use [this](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) package for make tree for categories

Is there a solution like hasmanythrough to get categories(with children) directly from the account?

Comment: You may follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257892/laravel-sub-categories-display-under-main-categories/54386915#54386915

Comment: @A.ANoman My question is about the relationship between the account and the category, not the category hierarchy